# pywin32 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

I'm using `python 3.6` and attempting to `import` `win32com.client` as `win32` to be able to send an email with outlook but keep getting the above `import error`.

I've installed both `pywin32` and `pypiwin32` and run the `postinstall` script (did see it say "You do not have the permissions to install COM objects.)

I see the `pywintpyes36.dll` and `pyhoncom36.dll` in the location I'm running the script out of.

I've done a bit of searching and can't seem to find what I'm missing.  Is it the fact that I was unable to install the COM objects?  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

[EDIT]

I'm working out of a venv, and have installed both libraries using `py -m pip install pywin32` and `py -m install pypiwin32`.  I verified that I see the installation in the "site-packages" folder within my venv.

my imports:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\path\venv\Lib\site-packages")
import tkinter as tk
import getpass
import os.path
import time
import os
import win32com.client as win32
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime
from functools import partial
```

I have the `sys.path.append` there otherwise the module is not found at all.

Full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\path\program.py", line 8, in <module>
import win32com.client as win32
File "C:\path\venv\Lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from win32 import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: How did you install the libraries? Where are you getting this error? Speaking of, please share the entire error message.

Comment: I installed them in a venv using pip -m install pywin32 and pip -m install pypiwin32.  Entire error message:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\program.py", line 9, in <module>
    import win32com.client as win32
  File "C:\path\venv\Lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from win32 import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

Comment: I'm getting the error on my `import win32com.client as win32` line of code (line 9 referenced in above error message)

Comment: Are you using `anaconda` now?

Comment: I am not.  I'm new to python and am not too familiar with anaconda, would that help in this situation?

Answer (score 5):

This may not be directly relevant for the OP, but may be of help to others who end up here based on the title.

#### Summary

Possible workaround for `conda` environments with `Python>=3.8`:

- DO NOT `pip install pywin32`, but
- DO `conda install pywin32` (e.g. from [conda-forge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39862730))

#### Details

I encountered the following error in a freshly created (Mini-)Conda environment with Python 3.9 on windows 10, after installing `pywin32` via `pip`:

`ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32file: The specified module could not be found.`

The [pywin32 installation instructions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32#installing-via-pip) mention this type of issue explicitly, and there are [several related issues](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1634#issuecomment-741053753).

However, in my case something else was going on.

Here are some interesting observations:

- I have numerous other, pre-existing, conda environments, with python versions ranging from 2.7 to 3.8, and corresponding `pywin32` versions, in which the issue does *not* arise (just verified this).
- All these environments have their own `pywintypesXX.dll` etc. yet they coexist peacefully.
- There is no `pywintypesXX.dll` in my `system32` folder.
- I have never needed to run the [pywin32_postinstall script](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/main/pywin32_postinstall.py), yet.

As it turns out, on my system, the import error only arises if I do a `pip install pywin32` in a `conda` environment with Python>=3.8. The issue does *not* arise for Python 3.7 (nor for 2.7).

In a Python>=3.8 conda environment, `conda install pywin32` fixed the issue (instead of using `pip`).

Apparently [Python 3.8 changed the way dll files are found](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#os). This change has been [incorporated in pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/commit/71afa71e11e6631be611ca5cb57cda526b5e91ab), but can still cause trouble if you mix `conda` and `pip`.

Related:

- [DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found. win32api, sys, os](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59277475)
- [How to fix "ImportError: DLL load failed" while importing win32api](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58612306)
- [How to fix 'DLL load failed while importing win32api' in Jupyter notebook after connecting VS code to Jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68226255)