# How to fix 'DLL load failed while importing win32api' in Jupyter notebook after connecting VS code to Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, pywin32

When I try using Jupyter notebook, kernel error appears like this

```
import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api:
```

After connecting vs code to jupyter notebook, error appears.

I've already tried

```
conda install pywin32
```

and copied the two files from [installation directory of Anaconda]\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32 to C:\Windows\System32

but it didn't work.

how to fix?

Answer (score 6):

Try  installing it using pip, it can solve your problem here

```
pip install --upgrade pywin32==225
```

Or this, if you don't have the package already

```
pip install pywin32==225
```

Answer (score 4):

After activating the env where the above is causing issue uninstall win32api (if it is installed):

```
pip uninstall pywin32
```

Then use pip to install pywin32:

```
pip install pywin32
```

Jupyter should work afterward. The solution is proposed here by [ValentinVerschinin](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4980)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Python 3.8? It seems to be a Python 3.8 specific problem.

Can you try to install the `pywin32==225`?

You can refer to [this page](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1431).

Answer (score 0):

Installing the relevant binary from [github](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases) worked for me