# Jupyter notebook unable to connect to kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tornado

Something has become messed up in a way that I don't understand.

I've been installing a lot of packages today and read that the error below may have been caused by installing an older version of tornado, which I have tried to correct by:

1. Opening Anaconda Navigator
2. Opening CMD.exe Prompt from Anaconda Navigator
3. commanding "pip install --user Tornado==6.3.2

Opening the developer tools in chrome (my chosen browser for Jupyter notebooks), I see a warning:

"DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://bmnlcjabgnpnenekpadlanbbkooimhnj/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT"

and an error:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8888/api/kernels/d6493f09-5917-41bc-8020-411dcc0f2105/channels?session_id=3745c017a6674a9d8b58ab96085a180e' failed

I've pasted a screenshot below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I miss running my python scripts!

[image]

Comment: Looking in C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime,

I can see that the kernel JSON file is empty. 

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling anaconda and jupyter a couple of times tonight, since I read that kernel errors can be really nasty. 

Neither uninstall & reinstall cycle fixed the issue. 

Should I delete the Appdata\Roaming\jupyter folder and then reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

Looking back at the error message while in a calmer state, I realised the error was from a missing DLL.

Following the instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68226255/how-to-fix-dll-load-failed-while-importing-win32api-in-jupyter-notebook-after), all that was need was to uninstall pywin32 and install pywin version 225:

```
pip uninstall pywin32

pip install pywin32==225
```

Now my jupyter notebooks open and run happily :)